# Как обновить OpenGL на ПК

Tags: windows, opengl, windows-7

у меня вопрос про OpenGL и драйвера видео карты, раньше у меня стоял Windows 8.1, на нём я обновил OpenGL до 2, при помощи обновления драйверов видеокарты.
Сейчас я установил Windows 7 самую новую, там по умолчанию стоит OpenGL 1.1, Я бы хотел его обновить до 2, но версия драйверов максимальная, и почему то нельзя откатить до старой.
Почему на Window 8.1 была OpenGL 2 а на Window 7 только 1.1?
Мне очень нужно хотя бы OpenGL  2, для работы с графическими программами.
Устанавливал драйвера через Driver booster. Моя видеокарта ATI Radeon x1600 pro.

Comment: Не знаю, какая у вас ситуация, но наверное будет проще выкинуть это старье и раздобыть что-нибудь не такое древнее. За 1000р куча б\у карточек на порядок лучше, чем эта.

Answer (score 0):

Доступная версия OpenGL определяется драйверами видеокарты. Драйвера, разумеется, выбираются из доступных для вашей ОС. Драйвера же, в свою очередь, дают ту версию, на которую (по их мнению) способна видеокарта.

Обновляйте драйвера видеокарты.

Но, похоже, x1600 это весьма старая карточка и больше чем OpenGL 2.1 не тянет.

Если я верно понимаю, официальных драйверов под Windows 7 даже не существует - https://www.amd.com/ru/support/graphics/legacy-graphics/ati-radeon-x-series/ati-radeon-x1xxx-series